# HTML page not rendered correctly on PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

First time i'm using PhoneGAP. We just design a responsive HTML template and i'll integrate it to Phonegap. I have Android SDK .

```
phonegap create testApp com.example.testapp testApp
cd testApp
phonegap build android
```

This command creating a testApp folder and putting an example Android project to *testApp/platforms/android/*

After this, i'm creating a new project with existed content on Eclipse ADT . And then, i'm copying our responsive template's *main.html* file and all other css, js and image files to *testApp/platform/android/assets/www* folder. And lastly copy paste this to *assets/www/index.html* file. (It's a workaround for a bug, [see here](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/app_dies_on_startup_connection_to_the_server_was_unsuccessful#reply_9415534))

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>tittle</title>
        <script>
            window.location='./main.html';
        </script>
    <body>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Now it should work, but it's not. I'm starting emulator and then **Run As Android App** on Eclipse, this is result. Blank (white) screen and a weird black box.

[image]

Can you tell me what is i'm missing?

Comment: your html is not correct, you r  missing head complit

Comment: @AmitPrajapati nothing changed. It's working on real devices, but not working on emulator.

Comment: I think you emulator have enable GPU

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem what I did was change the device I'm using a Galaxy Nexus to compile my app and test, you can try to disable your OpenGL render in UI. Also check out about `Genymotion`.